# Expanding {a..d} to a b c d in zsh

Tags: zsh, brace-expansion, grml

In bash, `{a..d}` expands to `a b c d`. Currently this is not happening for me in zsh, and my googling has returned conflicting results.

Some results suggest that `{a..d}` should work -http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion

The other result I found is from the zsh mailing list which suggests `setopt braceccl` to get letter ranges using `{a-z}`. This works, but I'm wondering whether I've misread the Brace-Expansion link, or whether there's something else to consider.

Importantly, I'm using the `zsh-grml` config, which is probably adjusting a variety of expansion options, but I'm hesistant to start digging through because it's massive, and a cursory `grep brace ~/.zshrc` doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: With `braceccl` you can do `{a-d}`, without only `{abcd}`. Form `{a..d}` doesn't work in any case, at least in my `zsh 5.05`. It is possible however that something has changed in newest version.

Comment: @jimmij `{a..d}` should work according to the brace-expansion section of the expansion document linked

Comment: This document is about zsh `5.0.7`, I do not see this paragraph in my zsh manual. It is very likely they added this feature recently, however I cannot see this in the release note: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/releases.html

Answer (score 6):

Works fine here with `zsh` v. `5.0.8`
Brace expansion with single characters was added in [Jan 2014](http://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/d26461a3c61b311bdbd58334ee5f8a5113dcdbf2/)<sup>1</sup> so if you're using a version prior to `5.0.6` then it's not available.

---

<sup>1: see also the discussion [here](http://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2014/msg00035.html)</sup>