# How to create multiple dot files using brace expansion?

Tags: zsh, brace-expansion

I want to create a bunch of dot files using brace expansion, but it doesn't work:

```
touch .{a..h}
```

the result is a file `.{a..h}` is created instead of

```
.a
.b
.c
...
```

Comment: What is your shell?

Comment: I am using zshell

Comment: Works fine for me in zshell. Which version are you using?

Comment: zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0)

Comment: What does `zsh -fc 'echo $ZSH_VERSION .{a..h}'` output?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have the [ignorebraces](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-IGNOREBRACES) enabled, so `zsh` do not perform brace expansion:

```
$ setopt ignorebraces
$ print -rl -- {1..10}
{1..10}
```

So try `setopt noignorebraces` and redo the task.

Comment: no, it doesn't work even after `setopt noignorebraces`.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/219008/38906 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To create .dot file
=>touch .{a..h}
But all the files will be hidden, need to do **ls -a** to list all hidden files.
[image]
To create multiple text file
=> touch {a..z}.txt

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't post [screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). They are often difficult to read, the content will not show up in search engine results, and the OP will need to type-copy command examples when trying to apply your solution. Instead, paste it into the question using code formatting.